# commas in Decimals using <Text>

Tags: react-native, decimal

I have a value which is in a  Holder which is supposed to show currency and it shows the currency directly from the REST API, fine and good , but rather than show the value like this

```
123,456,789.00
```

It shows like this `123456789.00` I have been trying to format it to no avail. Is there a way to do this in React Native? The holder is looking like this

```
{this.state.balance}
```

Searched the internet and could not come up with something good at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the number to comma seperated formate

```
class BalanceExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      balance: 123456789,
    };
  }
   numberWithCommas = (x) => x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  render() {
    return (
    <Text>{this.numberWithCommas(this.state.balance)}</Text>
    );
  }
}

export default BalanceExample;
```

Comment: You da boss! Many thanks for this! Works perfect here. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Use `toLocaleString()` to add those commas.

Sample Example:

```js
let num = 123456789.00

console.log(num.toLocaleString())
```

[image]

Full Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/trembling-nachos)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

let num = 123456789.1;
export default function App() {
  const toCommaConvertion = (num) => {
    num += 0.001;
    let str = [...num.toLocaleString()];
    str.pop();
    return str.join('');
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{toCommaConvertion(num)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Still the same, Does not add the commas